# Realtek rtl8821ce wifi driver problem in Linux Mint 18.2

Tags: drivers, realtek

I've installed Linux Mint 18.2 on my ThinkPad E470. I can't connect to wifi as no wireless option shows up. I searched around and found an old post with the exact problems as mine - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2187780. But the solution to it is old and doesn't work for the new linux. And, lspci doesn't list my wifi adapter model. I also tried the solution given by Pilot6(Can't post the link as i have an upper limit on no. of links). But it doesn't work. This is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`. https://pastebin.com/mMa6465h

```
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:505b]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:c024]
```

Please guide further.

Comment: @GAD3R I ran it. The output didn't change.

Comment: This is the complete output of lspci - https://pastebin.com/mf55ViFW

Comment: Can you add the `sudo lshw -C network` output?

Comment: Here it is - https://pastebin.com/Vgyf1JXi.

Comment: More detail about the wifi card can be found here http://listing.driveragent.com/c/pci/10ec/c821

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Worked solution (Requirements: **kernel >=4.11**) :

(**UPD: In the latest release of endlessm you need kernel version 4.15**)

1. Download driver directory from this repo:
   https://github.com/endlessm/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8821ce

You can do it by this link:
    https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https://github.com/endlessm/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8821ce

2. Unpack zip archive.
3. Change the **Makefile**. Line "export TopDIR ?= ..." to export "TopDIR ?= PATH TO EXTRACTED DIRECTORY".
4. make
5. sudo make install
6. sudo modprobe -a 8821ce

Comment: Thanks for the tip - that worked for me. It failed with kernel 4.11.12 though and I had to upgrade to 4.13 in order to make it happen. Also, fwiw, kernel-devel should be installed as well (for new installs)

Comment: I have written something like this,

export TopDIR ?= /Downloads/rtl8821ce

And get an error message like this, 
$ make
Makefile:821: /Downloads/rtl8821ce/rtl8821c.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/Downloads/rtl8821ce/rtl8821c.mk'.  Stop.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: @HaseebMahmud, 
1. Check if the file rtl8821c.mk really exists in the folder that you downloaded.
2. Probably, you wrote the wrong path in 'export TopDIR'. Try to wrote full absolute path there.

Comment: @Eugen Thanks. My mistake was not writing the "absolute path". It should be /home/username/Downloads/rtl8821ce instead of /Downloads/rtl8821ce. It works now.

Comment: The code will not compile. I get "error: implicit declaration of timer_setup". What can I do about this error?

Comment: To get the driver to compile for a 5.0 kernel (symptom: you get an ```access_ok``` macro error when compiling) apply the following patch https://pastebin.com/v6Udh1NZ.

Comment: Apologies: I am a rookie with Linux. I am following the above instructions and  cannot seem to properly specify the TopDIR. Here is my code verbatim:

export TopDIR ?= /home/josh/Drivers/rtl8821ce

When I type "cd /home/josh/Drivers/rtl8821ce" in Terminal, I am taken to the correct directory. Yet when I run make in that directory, I get the following error(s): 

make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-54-generic'
/home/josh/Drivers/rtl8821ce/Makefile:2157: home/josh/Drivers/rtl8821ce/hal/phydm/phydm.mk: No such file or directory