# 8821ce Realtek WiFi card errors

Tags: debian, wifi, realtek

I am trying to install the driver for the Realtek 8821ce in my laptop. I installed Debian 10. And I am completely without internet.

This is the solution I was following:
[Realtek rtl8821ce wifi driver problem in Linux Mint 18.2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379049/realtek-rtl8821ce-wifi-driver-problem-in-linux-mint-18-2)

I installed manually with a USB the `bc` utility deb package because it was returning an error. Now with the command make it works a while but in the end returns many errors. Please check the image attached.

[image: make errors]

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
would be the correct repo. manual how to install is in git repo.
use dkms-install.sh from that git repo.

Answer (score 0):

Had this error message a few days ago. In my case the error came from using a deprecated kernel header file in the source code (depending on your installed kernel header version). You might need to add the following include to your source file

```
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
```

In your case it seems not be included at 
all.

Answer (score 0):

```
git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
```

try this, as there is no official Linux driver for this chipset :(

Comment: you have mentioned `rtl8821CU` , But the request was for `rtl8821CE`, Is both similar, btwn I am newbie for linux network drivers, But I too face the same issue