# Can't Install rtl8821ce driver

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wifi, drivers, realtek

I've been trying to install the rtl8821ce driver for my linux mint laptop. So far, the instructions I've been following make sense, but when I try to run `sudo make` or just `make` I get the following error message:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-54-generic/build M=/home/hudson/Downloads/rtl8821ce  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-54-generic'
/home/hudson/Downloads/rtl8821ce/Makefile:2157: home/hudson/Downloads/rtl8821ce/hal/phydm/phydm.mk: No such file or directory
/home/hudson/Downloads/rtl8821ce/Makefile:2166: home/hudson/Downloads/rtl8821ce/rtl8821c.mk: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'home/hudson/Downloads/rtl8821ce/rtl8821c.mk'.  Stop.
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/hudson/Downloads/rtl8821ce' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/hudson/Downloads/rtl8821ce] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-54-generic'
Makefile:2237: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

[I'm using this guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379049/realtek-rtl8821ce-wifi-driver-problem-in-linux-mint-18-2)

Answer (score 0):

Install rtl8821ce driver

If you are using mint or ubuntu, you can tray it this way:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

- open a terminal
- copy and paste every line separately, then press
- wait until every process has finished
- reboot to load the module into the kernel, wifi and bluetooth should work now

For me (LinuxMint 19.2; all updated) this works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Since Ubuntu 20.04 the package manager contains *rtl8821ce-dkms* and is easily installable with `apt install rtl8821ce-dkms`.