# CentOS: Wireless adapter not found

Tags: centos, wifi, drivers

I have installed CentOS 7 on my new HP laptop which has Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter which I found out using 'lspci'. But I can't connect with wifi. It says wireless adapter not found. I have searched in \lib\firmware\rtlwifi but cant find rtl8822ce file. My laptop don't have LAN port, so I need wifi to work.

Comment: Check whether you have a similar problem https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400259/180954

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work.